# write and sort footer links alphabetically

Tags: php

```
<a class='footerlink' href='aboutus.php'>ABOUT US</a>
<a class='footerlink' href='impress.php'>IMPRESSUM</a>
<a class='footerlink' href='contact.php'>CONTACT</a>
//... etc - about 30 links total
```

Is there a way to write this markup in php and sort items alphabetically?

In the above example it should be - `ABOUT US` - `CONTACT` - `IMPRESSUM`

I tried by creating two arrays - `titles` and `links` and there is no problem to sort on of them but how to keep right links with the corresponding titles?

Thanks.

Comment: please post the code that you have done yet

Comment: i think you may have array like `$menu = [ [link => 'aboutus.php', text => 'ABOUT US' ] ]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting Data from mysql, the you can use `order by`

If you want to short from php and your data array like as below

```
 $menu = [ ['link' => 'aboutus.php', 'text' => 'ABOUT US' ], [ 'link' => 'impress.php', 'text' => 'IMPRESSUM' ] ];
```

Then you can sort as below

```
 function compare($a, $b)
 {
     return strcmp($a["link"], $b["link"]);
 }

 usort($menu, "compare");

 print_r($menu );
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that those links are saved into database, then
You can make a query like this

```
$data = "SELECT * FROM `footer_links` ORDER BY `title`"
```

This is automatically set the result in the alphabet order